# How to restrict display when user directly browse for second page?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have designed a webpage using few html files. I have an index.html file as homepage. I need to start displaying my webpage from index.html. It's working fine when opened the respective link. But when i browse the secondpage link in search bar, it navigates directly to secondpage skkiping the index page. how can i protect this behaviour?

Comment: Do you want a javascript solution, as this would be fairly easy using mod_rewrite and more secure.

Comment: ya.i want a javascript solution

Answer (score 1):

Have your server set a cookie when they visit the index page.

Test for the existence of that cookie on all the other pages, and redirect if it doesn't exist.

(Or don't bother, deep linking is a natural part of the WWW).

Comment: no @Quentin. we have designed webpage in 2 different domains(php-4pages & javascript-5pages) , then we are integrating both into one site. Is it possible on client side or i can handle it only on server side?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that you want a javascript solution instead of a solution with mod_rewrite: Add the following (untested) script to every page:

```
//Check if the cookie is set
if( document.cookie.indexOf( 'myuniqueindexcookie' ) == -1 ) {
  //It isn't, so redirect to the index page
  document.location = "http://my.site/my/index.php";
}
```

On index.php put the following line of javascript

```
document.cookie = "myuniqueindexcookie=1; expires=0; path=/";
```

Obviously, this will not work when the user turns off javascript.

Comment: when i used above code, the index.html is displaying as my 1st page, but i can't navigate to other html pages.

Comment: I forgot to add expiry to the cookie in the second code block. I think it now should work, but I am unable to properly test it on this computer.